# Add a text to WooCommerce orders displayed total price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Via the following hook I added the text to the total prices:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'custom_total_message_html', 10, 1 );
function custom_total_message_html( $value ) {

        $text_to_add_before_price  = 'excl. BTW '; //change text in quotes to your preferred text 
  

    return $text_to_add_before_price . $value;
}
```

Only I see that on the thank-you page it is not shown in the table. Is it possible to add text only for the price in the row 'total'?

[image]

In the example it is: € 20.35 but this should be € 20.35 excl. VAT. With the current hook this is only done in the shopping cart and the checkout page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For orders *(and email notifications)* use the following to add a custom text before order total line:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_order_total_line_html', 1000, 3 );
function custom_order_total_line_html( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = __('excl. BTW ') . ' ' . $total_rows['order_total']['value'];

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To add it after instead use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_order_total_line_html', 1000, 3 );
function custom_order_total_line_html( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    $total_rows['order_total']['value'] .= ' ' . __('excl. BTW ');

    return $total_rows;
}
```